# Rails/mysql SUM distinct records - optimization

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, query-optimization, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Hey. How would you optimize this SQL

```
SELECT SUM(tmp.cost) FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT clients.id as client, countries.credits_cost AS cost
   FROM countries
   INNER JOIN clients ON clients.country_id = countries.id
   INNER JOIN clients_groups ON clients_groups.client_id=clients.id
   WHERE clients_groups.group_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
   GROUP BY clients.id
) AS tmp;
```

I'm using this example as part of my Ruby on Rails project. Note that my nested SQL (tmp) can have more then 10 milion records. You can split that in more SQLs if the performance is better.
Should I add any indexes to make it quicker (i have it on IDs)?

Comment: Could you explain what this query is supposed to do?  It's very strange because A) DISTINCT clients.id doesn't seem to mean anything in that context, and indeed the need to select clients.id is not apparent at all, and B) You are grouping by clients.id, which means you will only get the cost from the first country, but there is no order so you will essentially get one arbitrary country for each client....

Comment: The inner SQL has DISTINCT attribute to eliminate all clients.id duplicates. The SQL works but I'm looking for optimization proposals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have indexes on all the foreign keys involved in this SQL code such as:
clients_groups.client_id, clients.country_id, **clients_groups.group_id**

However, mainly
When you have that number of entries, Using SQL functions such as SUM() or COUNT() can be performance killing
So I suggest you keep a cache of the cost and update it with each transaction affecting the cost.